# What could cause a sudden pop-up (explosion/blow off) noise inside the car while driving?

Tags: noise, hyundai, sonata

2006 Hyundai Sonata, V6, automatic transmission. I've owned the car for a year and a half now without any troubles. Today while driving there was a sudden explosive noise inside the car as if something blew off. I am not sure what this noise could be due to. The car's ac/heater/fan were off.  The car's battery is fairly new (less than a year with 5 year warranty).

Any ideas what that noise could have been due to?

Comment: Did you feel anything?

Comment: Nothing much other than a sudden shock on hearing that scary sound :-/

Answer (score 2):

Without any other symptoms or issues, I would assume you just ran over something that your tire threw into the body of your car.  Like a piece of a re-tread tire.

Look under the hood for anything that looks out of place and check under the car for any fluid that might be leaking.  If you don't find anything just keep driving and pay attention for anything unusual, just in case it is something other than road debris.

Comment: Even though I am not sure, my hunch is that it might be something related to air conditioner. I feel that way because it had not been working properly for quite some time and whenever I switched it on it made a hissing noise (not of fan).

Comment: @Pupil the hissing is most likely a symptom that your Freon is low in your A/C system, which would explain why it would not be blowing cold.